# Как данные с тега ссылки записать в массив?

Tags: html, javascript

Нужно данные с тегов ссылок записать в массив.

```
<div class="datetime">
  <div class="label fl_l">День рождения:</div>
  <div class="labeled fl_l">
    <a href="#">8 февраль</a> 
    <a href="#">1993 г.</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var linksData = [];

$('a').each(function() {
    linksData.push($(this).text());
});
```

Данный код сработает абсолютно для всех ссылок на странице. Если вам нужно в конкретном блоке, то делайте выборку так

```
$('.labeled a') .....
```

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы ориентированы на поддержку старых браузеров и IE - 2 варианта: jquery (простой, но нужно загружать целую библиотеку), js (кривой: нужно сделать универсальную функцию поиска по классу).
Если Вы рассчитываете, что у всех Ваших пользователей есть норм браузер - getElementsByClassName в помощь.
Если есть возможность к контейнеру, где хранятся ссылки, прикрутить id - самый наипростейший код js (код как и в варианте выше, но поддерживать будет больше браузеров).
Выбор за Вами.